# Ignoring only invalid query params in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using `f:viewparam` to capture GET request params to a JSF page.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{mediaGroupController.mediaGroupId}"/>
    <f:viewParam name="type" value="#{mediaGroupController.type}"/>
    <f:viewParam name="limit" value="#{mediaGroupController.limit}" converter="javax.faces.Integer" >
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="0"/>
    </f:viewParam>
</f:metadata>
```

This works OK if I enter valid parameters for all, like `?id=1&type=foo&limit=10`. However, if one of the params is invalid, for example, `?id=1&type=foo&limit=bar`, valid params like id and type are also ignored.

I would like to only ignore the `limit` parameter in such a case. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom converter which don't throw a `ConverterException`, but just returns `null` when the conversion fails.

E.g.

```
<f:viewParam name="limit" value="#{mediaGroupController.limit}" converter="limitConverter">
```

with

```
@FacesConverter("limitConverter")
public class LimitConverter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return (value != null) ? String.valueOf(value) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        return (value != null && value.matches("\\d+") ? Integer.valueOf(value) : null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have also posted an alternative solution, could you take a look and see if there are downsides to using that approach? I was basically thinking of doing the same thing for my date converters, and thought instead of rewriting the converter code, I should just delegate to the existing converters. Is it possible to add an AOP converter to all the converters, such that it will intercept any call to a converter, and catch the exception, and return null? I'm using Spring, maybe possible with Spring AOP?

Comment: I also thought of your alternative approach, but that seemed overkill for simple conversion. You can truly go for extending the standard converters. As to AOP, sorry I can't tell that as I don't have hands on experience with that.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach might be to extend the existing converter, and catch the exception and return `null` in that case.

```
@FacesConverter("limitConverter")
public class LimitConverter extends IntegerConverter{

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        try {
            return super.getAsString(context, component, value);
        } catch (ConverterException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        try {
            return super.getAsObject(context,component, value);
        } catch (ConverterException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```