# Using multiple <f:viewParam> on a JSF page along with custom converters and ignoring only invalid parameters whose conversion fails

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, viewparams

I have two `<f:viewParam>` tags enclosed within an `<f:metaData>` tag on a JSF page as shown below.

The index.xhtml file:

```
<h:form id="form" prependId="true">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="userId" id="paramId" rendered="#{not empty param.userId}" converter="#{userRoleConverter}" value="#{testManagedBean.userTable}"/>                
        <f:viewParam name="userRoleId" id="userParamId" rendered="#{not empty param.userRoleId}" converter="#{userAuthorityRowSelectionConverter}" value="#{testManagedBean.entity}"/>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{testManagedBean.preRenderEvent}" />
    </f:metadata>
    <p:messages id="messages" globalOnly="false" showDetail="true" showSummary="false" autoUpdate="false" closable="true"/>
</h:form>
```

each of them is associated with a converter as specified by the `converter` attribute.

When two parameters namely `userId` and `userRoleId` are appended as a querystring to the URL, two properties namely `userTable` and `entity` are set to the associated managed bean - `testManagedBean` after conversion is taken place by the converters specified.

The managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class TestManagedBean implements Serializable
{
    private UserRoles entity;    //Both are POJOs.
    private UserTable userTable;

    public TestManagedBean(){}

    //Setters and getters of both the properties entity and userTable.        

    public void preRenderEvent(ComponentSystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException
    {
        System.out.println((entity==null)+" : "+(userTable==null));
    }
}
```

---

When conversion fails on one of the properties, either `userId` or `userRoleId`, the other property along with the failed one is **also not** set to the managed bean (which is expected to be set because the conversion of this **other** property is not likely to fail) and both of them are null.

For example, if I entered a URL like,

`/index.jsf?userId=100&userRoleId=12`

then, the following statement in the `preRenderEvent()` method (associated with `<f:event>`),

```
System.out.println((entity==null)+" : "+(userTable==null));
```

displays `true : true`.

In this case, the conversion of `userId` fails (the value 100 doesn't exist in the database) but the conversion of `userRoleId` should succeed (but it doesn't) **and shouldn't be null** (which exists in the database).

---

Similarly, the following URL,

`/index.jsf?userId=1&userRoleId=120`

again displays `true : true`.

It is the reverse case of the previous one. `userId` exists in the database but `userRoleId` doesn't.

---

Finally, the following URL,

`/index.jsf?userId=1&userRoleId=12`

shows `false : false`. The values of both of the parameters in this case exist in their respective table in the database.

The failure of conversion is notified by throwing `ConverterException` that need not mention.

---

So, why is the value of both the properties set to null, when the conversion of one of them fails? Is only one of the converters executed, when conversion of one of them fails?

Comment: In converters, there is nothing to see. It is just like `if value doesn't exist in the database then, throw new javax.faces.convert.ConverterException(...)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139417/ignoring-only-invalid-query-params-in-jsf

Comment: Are you really still a child? I'm really impressed for the topics  that you're reviewing. Well, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a converter to validate, but a validator. Let the converter return `null` if nothing can be found (and throw `ConverterException` only if value is not interpretable as an user ID, i.e. it's inconvertible). Use `required="true"` instead if you'd like the value to be non-`null`.

E.g.

```
if (value == null) {
    return null;
}

if (!value.matches("[0-9]+")) {
    throw new ConverterException("Supplied parameter value can't be interpreted as an user ID.");
}

return service.getById(Long.valueOf(value)); // May return null if it doesn't exist.
```

By the way, the `rendered` attribute isn't making any sense there on `<f:viewParam>`. That's a taghandler which builds JSF component tree, not an UI component which renders some HTML. Even more, it's not [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewParam.html) at all. Also, it's somewhat strange to see `<f:metadata>` nested inside a form. Refer [When using <ui:composition> templating, where should I declare the <f:metadata>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856847/where-is-the-best-place-for-the-fmetadata-element)

Comment: Knowingly or unknowingly the `rendered="#{not empty param.userId}"` attribute of `<f:viewParam>` works though not documented, not sure why.